# 2 different PC and OS, one keyboard and mouse for both?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, fedora, synergy

I would like to install a new life in my old laptop. So I intended to Install Linux in it(I heard it was great to give it a second chance and I would learn to use Linux at the same time). The catch is that the keyboard is not working really well. 
So I was wondering if it was possible to use the keyboard/mouse from my new Laptop(which is running on windows 10) to control my old one.

I already googled it and I heard about Synergy. But my problem is quite specific
so before I get into it, I was wondering if it was possible.

Thank you! 
Lawnio

Comment: Just get a mouse and a keyboard that run on Bluetooth and allow you to switch between devices running on different channels. In this case, the question is better fit for [Hardware Recommendations SE](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Or just get USB mouse and keyboard for the laptop that needs it, or use it for both with a KVM switch.  All of this hardware is very inexpensive.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [synergy](http://symless.com/synergy/) for a long time with Windows(server) and Linux(client).

More recently It has been Mac(server) with Windows and linux clients.

It is possible. The two machines need to be on the same network.